# Почему «однородных» и «связанные» имеют разные окончания?

Tags: синтаксис, числительные, определения, словоизменение

> Запятая не ставится, если два однородных члена предложения, связанные повторяющимся союзом 'ни', образуют тесное смысловое единство (часто тогда, когда однородные члены предложения противоположны по значению).
>   (http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=1438)

Слова ***однородных*** и ***связанные*** относятся к слову ***члена***. Почему у них разные окончания? На мой взгляд, должно быть так:

Запятая не ставится, если два однородных члена предложения, связанных повторяющимся союзом 'ни', образуют тесное смысловое единство (часто тогда, когда однородные члены предложения противоположны по значению).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратимся к Розенталю.

> [§193. Определение при существительном, зависящем от числительных два, три, четыре](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_03)
> Если определение (обычно обособленное) стоит после счетного оборота, то чаще оно ставится в форме именительного падежа множественного числа, например:
> Направо от двери были два окна, завешенные платками (Л. Толстой); Последние два письма, писанные карандашом, меня испугали (Чехов); ...Два огромных осмоленных корыта, привалившиеся друг на друга... торчащие у самого выхода в открытую воду (Федин); Подкатили к колхозному амбару два грузовика, груженные мукой (Ю. Лаптев).

Выходит, цитируемые Вами авторы правы.